# Java Reflection - Get generic type, with possible generic of generic?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need to determine the generic type(s) applied to a Java `Object` at runtime.  For a situation like `Map<String, String>`, that is rather easy.  I have code that looks like this:

```
protected Class<?>[] getGenericParameterTypes(Field field) {
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
    Type[] types = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
    Class<?>[] ptClasses = new Class<?>[types.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        ptClasses[i] = (Class<?>) types[i];
    }

    return ptClasses;
}
```

This works fine for the simple use case.  What I'm struggling with is a situation that popped up where I have a more complex `Map`, like `Map<String, List<String>>` or `Map<String, List<List<String>>>`.  How do I apply this logic to get the types/parameterized types for this `Map`?

Comment: The problem is `(Class<?>) types[i]`.  Not every Type is a Class.  Have a look at the **All Known Subinterfaces** section in the [the documentation of Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GeantyRef](https://github.com/leangen/geantyref) (I am the maintainer) to pull off almost any type-level magic in Java:

```java
protected Class<?>[] getGenericParameterTypes(Field field) {
    List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    GenericTypeReflector.transform(field.getAnnotatedType(), new TypeVisitor() {
        @Override
        protected AnnotatedType visitClass(AnnotatedType type) {
            classes.add((Class<?>) type.getType());
            return super.visitClass(type);
        }
    });
    return classes.toArray(new Class[0]);
}
```

This will collect all leaf types. E.g. for `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Optional<Double>>>>`, you'd get `[String, Integer, Double]`.